# How to set a button listener dynamically in android?

Tags: android, button, reflection, listener

I'm developing an application that serves as a template for other apps and I need to create a menu with categories (the categories vary depending on the app). What I want is to create dynamically the menu. In a `JSON` file I define the necessary categories and dynamically create the items on the screen. What I intend to do is set to each category (`Button`) a `Listener` so that when you click on each perform a different action. To do this I'm using `Reflection`. Here is a code example of what I intend to do.

```
package com.example;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button myButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(CustomListener.create("MakeCallListener"));

}

static class CustomListener {

    public static OnClickListener create(String listenerName) {

        OnClickListener actionListener = null;

        try {

            Class<?> classListener = Class
                    .forName("com.example.MainActivity$" + listenerName);

            actionListener = (OnClickListener) classListener.newInstance();

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.i("debug", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.i("debug", e.getMessage());
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            Log.i("debug", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.i("debug", e.getMessage());
        }

        return actionListener;
    }
}

class MakeCallListener implements OnClickListener {

    public MakeCallListener() {}

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        /*
         * TODO: write the procedure to dial a phone number
         */
    }
};
```

}

The problem is I am getting a `InstatiationException`. The error message is:

01-01 03:00:25.683: I/Bluumi(14206): can't instantiate class com.example.MainActivity$MakeCallListener; no empty constructor

I have little experience using reflection and the solutions I've tried do not work.

This is the stack trace

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.MainActivity$MakeCallListener; no empty constructor
java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
com.example.MainActivity$CustomListener.create(MainActivity.java:36)
com.example.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I think your class is named com.example.MainActivity.MakeCallListener (replace $ with . $ is for anonymous classes)

Comment: @njzk2 thanks for your reply. If I do as you say I get an ClassNotFoundException so my approach is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to instanciate a Class which is not static from a static one.

This is not possible, as your MakeCallListener class does not exist in a static context (it is tied to an *instance* of MainActivity). Try to make it static, or to have your CustomListener class not static.

Comment: Definitely the exception not thrown for that reason. I tried to move the _create_ method of _CustomListener_ to the body of _MainActivity_ (so that method is an instance method) and that does not solve the problem. Keep generating an `InstantiationException` :$

Comment: can you post your stack trace ?